# if more than 2 column selected in list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this eloquent model query

```
public function getemployee(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $employees = mot_users::where("branch_no", $id)->lists('user_no', 'lastname', 'firstname');
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'employees' => $employees]);
}
```

the problem is this "->lists();" can only handle 2 columns which sent as a json response (seen through console, only 2 selected columns out of 3 is sent). How can I send 3 columns or more than 2 columns in the "->list()" or is there any alternative eloquent model query other than using "->list()" if its impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, just do a

```
$employees = mot_users::where("branch_no", $id)->get(array('user_no','lastname','firstname'))->toArray();
```

That should do the trick.

Note that if your model object has a relationship and this column relationship isn't part of what you try to `->get` you can't get an error.

Note 2 that here you're using the good ol' `$_POST`, you should consider using the [proper Request object](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) as seen in the doc.

Comment: thank you! @YoannCh, in regards of using proper request object, if i use "Request::input("id");" I get an error, however, if i use $_POST, i dont get one so I did use $_POST instead of "Request::input("id"); " even its inappropriate because im working with a framework.

Comment: Then you may have a problem in your controller or in your design. You should resolve that problem too @Code_Demon. Feel free to accept my answer btw ;)

Comment: I declared this in my controller "use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;" anything im missing or something wrong why i get an error if i use proper request object?

Comment: You should add the following : 
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: and then in your method prototype, the one that does the @Post doing the following : `public function yourFunctionWhateverItsName(Request $request)`

Comment: then you should be able in the method to do
`$id = $request->input('id');`

Comment: That's the dependency injection way. I prefered split all in separate messages so that it would look more clear I think and more readable.

Comment: correct one...+1